# php fatal error: Undefined class content drush

Tags: php, linux, drupal-8, drush

When I ask the drush status while im in the folder of the website I get this message

> /volume1/web/drupal8 $ drush status
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlmysql.php on line 56
>
> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlmysql.php on line 56
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error] Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlmysql.php, line 56

When I ask the drush status while im in the bin folder drush seem to work

> /bin$ drush status  PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/php.ini  PHP OS
>   :  Linux  Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush  Drush
>   version          :  8.1.5  Drush temp directory   :  /tmp  Drush
>   configuration    :  Drush alias files      :

I can't figure out what im doing wrong, how can I run drush on folder `/volume1/web/drupal8`?

thanks in advance

PDO is installed and enabled. I run `php56 -i`

> PDO PDO support => enabled PDO drivers => dblib, mysql, pgsql, sqlite
>
> pdo_dblib
>
> PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib => enabled Flavour => freetds
>
> pdo_mysql
>
> PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled Client API version => mysqlnd
>   5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd                              41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value pdo_mysql.default_socket =>
>   /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> pdo_pgsql
>
> PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled PostgreSQL(libpq) Version =>
>   9.3.6 Module version => 1.0.2 Revision =>  $Id: 0e858dd2051ca8c2fd3c781909a0670ab5fecd36 $ pdo_sqlite
>
> PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled SQLite Library => 3.10.2

Comment: do you have PDO properly installed?

Comment: Is pdo installed? Run ``php -m`` to check.

Comment: Yes PDO is installed

Comment: I run `$ php56 -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
apcu
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache`

Comment: @Robert how do I know it's properly installed?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you don't have properly installed `PDO_MYSQL`. You need to invoke `phpinfo()` function and see if this module is present. The constant `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` comes from PDO library. If php is invoked from CLI then probably it has its own `php.ini` so you need to enable PDO there as well.

To check if you have enabled PDO in PHP CLI run `php -m |grep PDO` the command should return `PDO` string.

To install PDO check the [PHP Manual for Installing PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php).

Comment: I run `/volume1/web/drupal8$ php56 -m | grep PDO
PDO`

Comment: I post de PDO in my question , PDO is enabled.

Comment: try to make simple script that connects to mysql via pdo, then change it to connect via SSL and see if it works

Comment: I checked permissions `ls -la /volume1/@appstore`  and made symbolic links `ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /volume1/@appstore/composer
ln -s /usr/local/bin/drush /volume1/@appstore/drush`

Comment: I have an other problem now discribed here, will you please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748604/i-can-run-drush-status-everywhere-but-not-in-a-drupalsite

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue as well on all drupal 7 and 8 directory, while drush works fine outside drupal, it doesn't work in Drupal directory. the error says:

```
Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in Drush\Sql\Sqlmysql->creds() (line 56 of phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlmysql.php).
```

Installing php-mysql (or php5-mysql) fix the issue.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)